# How to make browser go to a URL with query string when clicking a link using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose now I'm under `http://mysite.com/index.html`, index.html contains below html:

```
    <ul>
        <li><a data="value">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a data="value2">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a data="value3">Link3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I hope:

When I click Link1, browser will go to `http://mysite.com/mypage.jsp?q=value`

When I click Link2, browser will go to `http://mysite.com/mypage.jsp?q=value2`

How can I achieve this with jQuery?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why with jQuery / JavaScript? Why don't you just add the `href` tag with those values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this :

```
$("a[data]").click(function(e) { 
   //added the data attribute to the selector 
   //prevent default href action
   e.preventDefault();
   //change url
   location.href = "http://mysite.com/mypage.jsp?q=" + $(this).attr("data");
});
```

Or simply your HTML could become like this :

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://mysite.com/mypage.jsp?q=value">Link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://mysite.com/mypage.jsp?q=value2">Link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://mysite.com/mypage.jsp?q=value3">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The use of `[data]` in the selector in important to avoid to change the behavior of all the links in the page (edited answer). Also he wants the use of jQuery.

Comment: @glautrou yes youre right. But i was just making a generic point here. And nothing wrong in providing different options. Note that the OP's HTML didnt have `href` in them. So he might not know that there's such a tag existant. jQuery resorting should only be the last option to use when it comes to front end dev.

Answer (score 1):

maybe just add href to your link so it will work even without javascript/jquery

if you really want a javascrip solution you should use

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

if you want a jquery solution

```
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";    
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[data]").click(function(){
   e.preventDefault();
   window.location.href = "http://mysite.com/mypage.jsp?q=" + $(this).attr("data");
});
```